# Store different positional numbers on a variable

Tags: powershell

I have this output written to a text file:

```
DataStore_Checksum.txt:65:esentutl : ERROR: page 3401 checksum failed
DataStore_Checksum.txt:69:    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: page 3401 checksum failed:String) [], RemoteException
DataStore_Checksum.txt:73:ERROR: page 6131 checksum failed
DataStore_Checksum.txt:74:ERROR: page 6357 checksum failed
```

I need to store every page number that failed a checksum. In this case, `[3401, 6131, 6357]`.

I tried using two ways:

```
ToString().Split(' ')[2]
'\d pattern matches
```

But the line content position for the page number is different on every line. And for some reason the `\d` syntax doesn't work with `Select-String` or `-Split`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57467846/45375) with a more concise alternative, assuming that it is acceptable to load the entire input file into memory:

```
[regex]::Matches((Get-Content -Raw file.txt), '(?<=\bERROR: page )\d+').Value
```

- `[regex]::Matches()` finds all matches in the input string of the specified regex.
- Negative look-behind assertion `(?<=\bERROR: page )` finds string `ERROR: page` without including it in each match, so that matches comprise just the page number (`\d+`).
- Accessing the `.Value` property on all matches then returns just an array of page numbers (as strings).

The above yields a regular PowerShell array (`[object[]]`) with all page numbers:

```
3401
3401
6131
6357
```

If there is a need to eliminate duplicates:

- If duplicates are always *grouped together*, pipe the command above to `| Get-Unique`
- If they're *not* grouped, pipe to `| Select-Object -Unique`.
- If you want to *sort* by page numbers while eliminating duplicates, pipe to 
  `| Sort-Object -Unique` as in Mathias' answer.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `\d` is a syntactically valid regulard expression, and will work with `Select-String`, but since the numbers you want are always surrounded by the same pattern of text, ie.:

```
ERROR: page #NUMBER# checksum failed
```

you would probably have better luck capturing all consecutive digits *in that context* with `Select-String` instead:

```
$pageNumbers = Select-String 'ERROR: page (\d+) checksum failed' -Path .\file.txt -AllMatches |ForEach-Object {
    # grab the (\d+) capture group
    $_.Match.Groups[1].Value
} |Sort-Object -Unique    # filter out duplicates
```

Comment: Thank you Mathias, this is very valuable as well.